# String input of more than one word causes exception error

Tags: java, output, user-input

I am inputting the following things:

- book
- 12.46
- music cd

For some reason, the prompt for cost comes up and the next output line comes on the same line. Could someone help me to spot my mistake?

```
public class SalesTax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Input items for shopping cart
        HashMap<String, String> cart = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // variables
        char done;
        boolean goods;
        double tax;

        // Pick items for list.
        do {       
            System.out.print("Please enter an item.");
            String item = input.next();

            System.out.print("Please enter the price for "+ item + ": ");
            String price = input.next();      

            if (item.contains("book")) {
                goods = false;  
            } else if(item.contains("chocolate")) {
                goods = false;
            } else if(item.contains("pill")) {
                goods = false;
            }

            cart.put(item, price);
            System.out.print("Would you like to continue to add items? (Type Y) for Yes and (Type N) for No.");
            done = input.next().charAt(0);

        } while(Character.toUpperCase(done) == 'Y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.println` or add a `System.out.flush()` before you call `input.next().charAt(0)`

Comment: I still get the same problem and I used System.out.flush. Does it matter where I put it?

Comment: Yes. It matters where you put it.

Answer (score 2):

**problem:**

```
String item = input.next();
```

By the time you input `music cd` it will consume **music** by `item` and `price` will consume the **cd** thus skipping it.

**solution:**

you need to call `input.nextLine();` to consume the whole line of string

Comment: When I do that the same problem happens but when inputting the next item and price on the same line

Answer (score 0):

you are using `System.out.print()` instead use System.out.println();

`print()` will just print the word and stays on the same line.

`println()` will print the whole line and cursor goes to second line .

And don't use the spaces while reading as you are writing it as

`input.next();`

> The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token. Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated next method will block.

**edit:**
just change the declaration to this.

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\n");
```

It will change the delimiter to new line and read the complete line.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `next()` just gets input upto a whitespace so you'd have to use `nextLine()` instead, which will read in the whole line of input upto a carriage return.

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same error but only earlier in the code

Answer (score 0):

use `input.nextLine()` to read an entire line from the keyboard. Means what ever the user typed till the user presses the enter key.

One thing that I did not understand is, what is the use of having this in your code

```
        if(item.contains("book"))
        {
            goods = false;  
        }
        else if(item.contains("chocolate"))
        {
            goods = false;
        }
        else if(item.contains("pill"))
        {
            goods = false;
        }
```

???
Can you please explain?

Thanks,

Comment: It is a Sales Tax problem and certain items do not get taxed. So if the user inputs a certain word like "milk chocolate", the program will read it and know it won't get taxed